# Java Algorithm constraints check failed on key RSA with size of 1024bits

Tags: java, ssl, keystore

After generating java keystore with: -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048
and configuring the java.security policy with:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, RSA keySize < 2048
```

I keep getting errors:

> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on key RSA with size of 1024bits

I’m using the following command to generate a 2048bit RSA key:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore star_domain_name.jks -storetype PKCS12 -dname "CN=*.domain_name.com,OU=Engineering, O=Company Name., L=City Name, ST=State, C=US" && keytool -certreq -alias server -file star_domain_name.com.csr -keystore star_domain_name_io.jks
```

I then verify the above with:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect localhost:443
```

That shows:

```
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
```

I also view the keystore with:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore star_domain_name.com.jks
```

Which shows:

```
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  67:4C:04:90:35:etc...etc...
         SHA1: AD:C8:06:74:3A:F1:72:etc...etc...
         SHA256: C5:D6:81:3B:C1:F7:CE:2D:43:91:06:E9:9etc...etc...
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
```

Everywhere I look I see 2048-bit RSA key.
However, when I want to use the java keystore in my java spring boot application, it keeps complaining:

> - Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on key RSA with size of 1024bits
> - Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints

As soon as I edit the java.security file, and remove RSA keySize < 2048 from it, and restart the application, everything works…

Is this because I did not import a signed domain cert?
Why does the application complain although I clearly configured the policy and the java keystore for 2048 bits?

My java application configuration contains:

```
ssl.key-store: /opt/cert_path/star_domain_name.com.jks
ssl.enabled: true
ssl.key-store-password: the_password_etc...
ssl.key-store-type: PKCS12
ssl.key-alias: tomcat
```

As soon as I edit the java.security file, and remove RSA keySize < 2048 from it, and restart the application, everything works…

Is this because I did not import a signed domain cert and the keystore is empty? I doubt it.

Why does the application complain although I clearly configured the policy file and the java keystore for 2048 bits?

The java.security file also contains:

```
jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024
```

Should that also be adjusted?

I've actually tried to adjust that, but that had no effect...

Comment: Hi & welcome to [so]! Interesting question! would you also share/tell us your java version?

Comment: and `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException` .... "try also" `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms` (...additionally to `jdk.tls...` and `jdk.jar...`)

Comment: ..as i understand problem/question: the *2048* key fails., @user207421 . And confusing 1: "As soon as I edit the java.security file, and remove RSA keySize < 2048 from it, and restart the application, everything works…" ..and 2. confusing: "Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on key RSA with size of **1024bits**"

Comment: you *think*, you have a 2048 key, @SUP3RS3T, but "confusing 1. + 2."(my previous comment)  match the fact, that "spring boot uses another key with 1024b"!

Comment: Which version on JDK do you use? do you have JSSE?

Answer (score 8):

I was stuck with that for a long time, and finally, I have found the solution.

So whenever I modified the file `java.security`, it would have no effect, because there is a second file `java.config` (on Linux it is located: `/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/java.config`) that overrides the params in `java.security`.

This is controlled by the property (in `java.security`):

`security.useSystemPropertiesFile=true`

So, either change that property to `false`, or modify params directly in `java.config`.

This has worked for me!

Comment: Thank you!!!! after 12 hours of frustrating...

Comment: Glad to help you! I had also that kind of frustration .

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add to this. After enabling cert debugging via adding

```
-Djava.security.debug=certpath
```

So, as an example:

```
java -Xms64m -Xmx512m -Djava.security.debug=certpath -Dspring.config.location=config.file -jar appname.jar &>> logfile.log &
```

I'm finally able to see why is Java complaining.
Apparently encrypted AWS RDS Instances use SSL cert that's 1024 bit. When my java applications call it, they fail because their policy is set to only accept RSA < 2048 keySize.

I contacted AWS for further guidance.

If anyone is struggling to troubleshoot Java cert issues, make use of:

```
-Djava.security.debug=certpath
```

It's extremely helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully handled those errors about RSA key sizes by changing the Java configuration to allow the key size used by the destination server I was trying to communicate.
It's pretty much what was covered by the other answers here, but this way you'll be sure all bases are covered.

1. Find all java.config and java.security files on your OS file system:

> find / -iname java.config

> find / -iname java.security

2. Verify which crypto policy your system is currently applying (it could be DEFAULT, LEGACY or FUTURE):

> update-crypto-policies --show

3. Access (vi/nano) the java.config file related to your current policy and also the java.security, and find configurations regarding RSA key size (RSA keySize < X or RSA keySize >= Y). On each one, change the operator and value that follows to suit your needs, and then save the file. For example, if your error message complains about a RSA 1024 bit key, you should have the following, which means you're not allowing keys lesser than 1024 bits, so 1024 or above will be fine:

> RSA keySize < 1024

4. Restart your service.

That's it.
The guide above assumes you're using Linux, but if you're not, you can adjust the commands to your OS.